# which packages are required to install wine in offline mode

Tags: wine, package-management

I want to install wine1.4 on approximately 20 PCs, but don't know how many packages are required for that. I've checked dependencies with `apt-cache showpkg wine1.4` but for some packages it gives an error like:

```
E: Can't select candidate version from package ttf-symbol-replacement as it has no candidate
```

Following are the packages listed in dependencies:

```
1.4.1-0ubuntu7 - debconf  debconf-2.0  libc6 libgettextpo0 binfmt-support procps dpkg dosbox cups-bsd fonts-droid fonts-liberation 
fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gnome-exe-thumbnailer kde-runtime ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-wqy-microhei winbind winetricks 
xdg-utils wine1.0 ttf-symbol-replacement ttf-symbol-replacement-wine1.3 ttf-tahoma-replacement wine wine1.2 ttf-symbol-replacement 
ttf-symbol-replacement-wine1.3 ttf-tahoma-replacement wine wine1.0 wine1.2
```

I've managed to download 21 packages out of that. It's obvious that I am going wrong somewhere, so whats the exact procedure to check all dependencies and download those packages?

Comment: not really an answer but an hint: maybe you want to take a look at apt-cacher-ng

Comment: sorry for second comment but i was to slow to edit the first one: with the apt-cacher-ng you have the possibility to use the program as it is intended or copy the apt-cacher-ng cache and try out the "import" function of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very hard to decide which packages are required to your machine for installing wine. It is possible that some packages may be already installed on your system by some other applications.

> I followed these steps to install wine on different machine. 
>   note: 32bit architecture files won't work on 64bit and vise versa.

1. all of you systems should be on same OS architecture. i.e. 32bit or 64bit.
   if you have different machine with different architectures then follow this procedure respectively
2. clear you local repository

   `sudo apt-get autoclean`

   `sudo apt-get update`
3. you have to make standard installation on at least single system.

   `sudo apt-get install wine`
4. now get those all packages.

   `mkdir ~/wine_packages`

   `sudo cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb ~/wine_packages`
5. now carry this `wine_packages` folder on different system place all files in archives

   `cp wine_packages/* /var/cache/apt/archives/`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install wine`

I didn't find a way to fonts, so we may exit with broken installed wine.. but `-f` will fix any error if present.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Synaptic
2. Check Wine 1.4 for installation
3. From menu: File → Generate package download script
4. Use that script within the on-line machine to download all needed packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the dependencies of wine and download all deb files, you can use [Cube](https://launchpad.net/camicricube). It is a portable and offline package manager. You can also use this to install the deb files on different computers (with same distribution and architecture)

You can check on how to use it [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1583)